# How to remove indents produced from double digit numbering in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, indentation, word-processing

The image below accurately describes my woes:

[image: 1]

I want it to look like the following, but I really don't know how:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply turn on the ruler (from the *View* tab) and adjust the *Left Indent* to set a common left margin for all the lines:

Before:
[image: 1]

During:
[image: 2]

After:
[image: 3]